# How do I get the size of an area of a QVBoxLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

[image]

This is the structure I have. I want to find the total size of label_2, or the QVBoxLayout, as it's displayed. When I use `verticalLayout_2->width()`, I always get 100 and `verticalLayout_2->height()` always returns 30. It's set to expanding, so I thought it would fill the area, which is 385x379, according to Qt Creator.

Doing `label_2-width()` and `label_2-height()` also results in 100x30, regardless of the window size and the area I thought it would expand to.

Comment: You are (probably) checking the sizes before the layout has been completely done. Try checking later.

Comment: It's after `ui->setupUi(this)`, should that be enough? Any later and it's getting into the running program.

Comment: I don't think that's enough. Try handling [`showEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent), I think the layout is done at that point (not 100%, haven't used that in a long while.)

Comment: I tried `ui->label_2->update();` before getting the size, but I get the same results.

Comment: I also tried running it later, in a different function that's called from the constructor, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Layout needs to be finished for the sizes to be valid. It won't be finished in your constructor (AFAIR), you need to check later.

Comment: you could run a QTimer with a 1msec timeout calling a slot reading your size.

Comment: Cool. Those answers were on the right track. After searching, I found [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6530), and using the suggestion by Volker, except removing `QDialog::showEvent( event );` solved it!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much visually going on after your widget's constructor has been run. The `setupUi` call happens in the constructor. The real work happens once the event loop gets going.

Your real problem is that you should not be checking the size at an *arbitrary* point in time. You should be checking it *each time it changes*. To do this, you need your own layout. All it takes is to derive from an existing layout, and reimplement `setGeometry`. This method is called each time the parent widget or parent layout resizes the given layout. That is the only correct approach, and it doesn't require any hacks to accomplish.

For example, the following class could be used to signal when there's a new geometry:

```
class SigBoxLayout : public QBoxLayout {
  Q_OBJECT
protected:
  void setGeometry(const QRect & r) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    if (r != geometry()) emit hasNewGeometry(r);
    QBoxLayout::setGeometry(r);
  }
public:
  SigBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::Direction dir, QWidget * parent = 0) : 
    QBoxLayout(dir, parent) {}
  Q_SIGNAL void hasNewGeometry(const QRect & r);
};
```